# Assertion Failure Error, vector subscript out of range problem in C++

Tags: c++, vector

My aim is to set `vec` array to `intData` array. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991070/debug-assertion-failed-vector-subscript-out-of-range) and applied it to my code. I resized intData before doing the process. In C# this `intData = GetIntArrayFromByteArray(vec);` creates no problem but I am confused when it comes to array vectors in C++. I stated where I get the error as a comment. I tried resizing but it didn't work. Can someone help me please?

Code explanation;

- `buf` gets a message(**it is not empty I get message from client**)
- I create a vector array `vec` same size as `buf`
- `GetIntArrayFromCharArray()` converts char vector array into int array
  vector.

  ```
      char buf[1550];//message gets here not empty
      vector<uint16_t> intData; //empty int vector
      //char buf ----> vecor<char> vec

      int n = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]);
      vector<char> vec(buf, buf + n);
      intData.resize(vec.size());//here I resize


      /*
         irrelevant code piece runs here
      */


      if (something == 1)// First fragment
      {
          intData = GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vec);//size out of range error here

      }
  ```

This is `GetIntArrayFromCharArray()` does the conversion

```
vector<uint16_t> GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vector<char> arr)
{
    // If the number of bytes is not even, put a zero at the end
    if ((arr.size() % 2) == 1)
        arr.resize(arr.size()+1);
    arr.push_back(0);


    vector<uint16_t> intArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i += 2)
        intArray.push_back((uint16_t)((arr[i] << 8) | arr[i + 1]));

    return intArray;
}
```

Comment: In `intData.resize(..); intData = GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vec);` `resize` is unneeded.

Comment: @Jarod42 without it, still gives the same error

Comment: I didn't say it is/fix the error, just that it can safely be removed.

Comment: @Selen Instead of adding a **[Solved]** mark at your question, you can simply accept the answer you were given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// If the number of bytes is not even, put a zero at the end
if ((arr.size() % 2) == 1)
    arr.resize(arr.size()+1);
arr.push_back(0);
```

Whoops!

This is actually:

- "If the number of bytes is not even, put a zero at the end"
- "Then always put another zero at the end"

The consequence is that you will *always* have an odd number of elements. This breaks the subsequent loop as you try to read one past the end of the vector.

I don't think you meant to put that `push_back` there, or perhaps you meant to have it *instead* of the `resize` call.

---

By the way, as Jarod pointed out, resizing `intData` up-front is a complete waste of time since the next thing you do with it (as far as we can see) is to replace the whole vector.

Comment: the whole code is so complicated I tried to simplfy it but it looks like some steps are unnecessary which are actually not. Should I upload full code ?

Comment: You could instead just follow my suggestion?

Comment: _"it looks like some steps are unnecessary which are actually not"_ If they are not related to the question, you should abstract them away (read: pretend they don't exist) as they are irrelevant. This is part of constructing a [mcve].